# Is there scala plugin compatible with Spring Source Tools Suit?

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework

I am using STS based on eclipe 2.6.2 and there is a scala plugin for eclipse

http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide

but it is not compatible with STS.

Is there anything other plugin.

I mainly need it debug play framework scala projects.

Comment: You might want to ask this question on the Scala IDE User's list:  http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "it is not compatible"?

Comment: Best of luck - I tried getting Eclipse + Play/Scala and it did not work out. Scala version 2.9.0.1, Play! 1.2.2RC1 with Play-Scala 0.9.1. I eventually had to use IntelliJ with Scala 2.8 to get Play project working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Eclipse IDE for Scala should work with STS. I just tried it with version 2.6.1.RELEASE (build id 201105041000).

Make sure you do **not select** JDT Weaving for Scala when installing the Scala plugin. The JDT weaving component is provided already by STS (albeit an older version). The Scala plugin comes with a newer version, that upsets the AspectJ plugin (included by STS).

Even easier, you can use the Dashboard view, 'Extensions' page. You can check the Scala IDE from there, and it correctly leaves out the JDT weaving plugin.

If you have any other issues, use the mailing list (scala-ide-user@googlegroups.com) or file a ticket.